# Udev rule to change ATTR{name} of a device

Tags: linux, usb, udev

Is there a way to change the default ATTR{name} of a given device [not the name of the device node]. The trivial solution of writing an udev rule to do it ends up in a permission error, so I wonder if that is the right way to do it.

Comment: depends which type of device

Comment: It is an input device (a keyboard)

Answer (score 0):

> > depends which type of device
>
> It is an input device (a keyboard)

No, not without re-writing the kernel.

The file is read-only.

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/input/input0/name
-r--r--r--. 1 root root 4096 Feb  6 12:03 /sys/class/input/input0/name
```

There is no ioctl() to set the name of an input device (only to get it).

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.20/include/uapi/linux/input.h#L124

At the generic device level, there is no way to pass parameters for specific devices when they are detected by a driver.  You can unbind a driver from a specific device, and you can try bind it manually, but there is no way to pass a parameter when you bind it.  See the LWN.net article, [Manual driver binding and unbinding](https://lwn.net/Articles/143397/).